# reference request: Postnikov towers for non-simply-connected spaces

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've read that for a space $X$ which is connected but not necessarily simply-connected, we can no longer obtain the $n^{\rm th}$ layer $P_nX$ of the Postnikov tower for $X$ as the pullback of a path-loops fibration (with contractible total space).  Instead, there is a pullback diagram
$$ \begin{array}{ccc} P_nX & \rightarrow & B\pi_1 X \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ P_{n-1}X & \rightarrow & K(\pi_nX,n+1) \times_{\pi_1 X} E \pi_1X \end{array} $$
(where the fiber is of course still $K(\pi_nX,n)$).  Does anyone know of a reference for this?  I checked the two books I have on hand -- Hatcher and Switzer -- but neither of them covers this.

Comment: To see one thing that goes wrong in the nonsimply connected setting (that the fundamental class of the fiber for $P_n X \to P_{n-1} X$ is not transgressive, that one cannot continue the fibration $P_n X \to P_{n-1} X$ and also that the lower right hand corner is not a fibration sequence) see my question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/257493/the-inability-to-continue-a-fibration-sequence-even-when-a-delooping-exists?noredirect=1#comment635241_257493

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your $B\pi_1X$ should be something else... What is the right-hand vertical map supposed to be?

In any case, this should do:

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-16/issue-2/Moore-postnikov-systems-for-non-simple-fibrations/10.1215/ijm/1256052280.full)

C. Robinson "Moore-Postnikov Systems for non-simply connected spaces"

In particular the beginning of section 4 (his $\hat{K}$ is the same as the Borel construction that you have, I think.)

Comment: Haha.  Just in the nick of time -- I'm talking about G--H obstruction theory to the postdoc working group in about 75 minutes (and this is the toy example).  I found this in Angeltveit's notes from Talbot '07, but he didn't give a reference for this.  I agree that something is fishy, I wasn't sure what the right vertical map was supposed to be either.

Comment: My guess was the following: start with $K(\pi_n X,n) \hookrightarrow * \twoheadrightarrow K(\pi_n X,n+1)$, cross the second map with $E \pi_1X$ to get $K(\pi_n X,n) \hookrightarrow E\pi_1X \twoheadrightarrow K(\pi_n X,n+1) \times E\pi_1X$, and then quotient by $\pi_1X$.  But the dangerous thing is that that map actually isn't $\pi_1X$-equivariant unless $* \twoheadrightarrow K(\pi,n)$ was, and I don't see how to guarantee that this is true.  (On the other hand, I'm *still* without a true equivariant bone in my body...)

Answer (score 2):

The first Postnikov invariant  for a pointed, connected space $X$ is $k^3\in H^3(\pi_1(X), \pi_2(X))$ and is also represented by a "crossed sequence" 
$$0 \to \pi_2(X) \to C_2 \to C_1 \to \pi_1(X) \to 1$$
where $C_2 \to C_1$ is a **crossed module**. There is quite a lot of information on such invariants, including some specific calculations of these, in the book partially titled [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html)  (EMS Tracts in Mathematics vol 15, 2011).

More examples are given in Graham Ellis and Luyen Van Le,  "Homotopy 2-Types of Low Order" J. Experimental Math, 2014.

Loday's 1982 JPAA paper   "Spaces   with  finitely   many   non trivial        homotopy     groups" has a lot of relations with higher Postnikov invariants.